# How to allocate a dynamic array in nasm assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm, dynamic-arrays

I've looked through tons of examples, but all the code I found was for defining an array of a set size such as

```
array1  resd 10
```

I want to write code that prompts user to enter numbers, into an array, until he wants to stop. Is there someway to allocate a dynamic array?

I also thought of storing the input somewhere and incrementing a counter. Then create an array once the user finishes inputs. But then, where would I store the inputs?

Edit: for 64-bit linux

Comment: Which operating system are you targeting?

Comment: Either get memory with `sys_brk` or `sys_mmap` and manage it yourself, or "just call malloc()". The latter is probably preferred.

Comment: If you use the array only locally (the data may be lost when doing a "ret" instruction) you may also allocate the data on the stack.